# FacebookOAuthClient - Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Contracts' or one of its dependencies

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing a .net 3.5 project in VS2008 and I'm trying to use FacebookOAuthClient. The problem is that I keep getting, "Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Contracts' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to download a new version of the Facebook C# SDK? of course you have to add the dll as reference...

eventually if you still get this error can you post a sample page of your application so I can check it in my environment?

Cheers